# Foreach loop in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using fullcalendar (JSON) and want to use a `foreach` loop in a multidimensional array. What I've got is this:

```
echo json_encode(array(

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => $arr['new'][0] . ' new',
        'start' => $arr['booking_date'][0],
        'url' => "bookings/new/1",
        'color' => '#F7F8E0',
        'textColor' => 'black'
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => $arr['completed'][0] . ' completed',
        'start' => $arr['booking_date'][0],
        'url' => "bookings/completed/1",
        'color' => '#D8D8D8',
        'textColor' => 'black'
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => $arr['accepted'][0] . ' accepted',
        'start' => $arr['booking_date'][0],
        'url' => "bookings/accepted/1",
        'color' => '#E0ECF8',
        'textColor' => 'black'
    ),
));
```

Now i have to input every array manually,  but how can I use foreach to do that for me?

I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.
echo json_encode(array(

```
    foreach($arr as $row) {
    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => $arr['new'][0] . ' new',
        'start' => $arr['booking_date'][0],
        'url' => "bookings/new/1",
        'color' => '#F7F8E0',
        'textColor' => 'black'
    ),
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
<?php
$array = array();

$arr = array(
    array(
        'new' => array("Title 1"),
        'booking_date' => array("Booking date 1")
    ),
    array(
        'new' => array("Title 2"),
        'booking_date' => array("Booking date 2")
    )
);

foreach($arr as $row) {
    array_push($array, array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => $row['new'][0] . ' new',
        'start' => $row['booking_date'][0],
        'url' => "bookings/new/1",
        'color' => '#F7F8E0',
        'textColor' => 'black'
    ));
 }

echo json_encode($array);
```